# Mediaplayer stops playing after playing a few times

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio, media-player

I've got a button that on press it plays a random sound clip followed by another and then another via one mediaplayer however after pressing the button numerous times (15-20 times) all audio just stops. I'm releasing the mediaplayer after the last audio clip is played so I don't see that being the reason. Any pointers?

```
public class Main extends Activity {


MediaPlayer mp;
Button generate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound);

}

public void youSir (View view)
{
    generate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;
    switch (randomInt){
    case 1: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beg); mp.start();
    break;
    case 2: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.begone); mp.start();
    break;
    case 3: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.begtwo); mp.start();
    break;
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        // @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

            audioTwo();
         }
    });

}


protected void audioTwo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;
    switch (randomInt){
    case 1: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.start); mp.start();
    break;
    case 2: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.end); mp.start();
    break;
    case 3: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mid); mp.start();
    break;
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        // @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            audioThree();
         }
    });
}

protected void audioThree() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;
    switch (randomInt){
    case 1: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.three); mp.start();
    break;
    case 2: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two); mp.start();
    break;
    case 3: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one); mp.start();
    break;
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        // @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            generate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old question but I try to answer it in case someone else has a similar problem.

You are running out of audio resources. The code actually does not release all `MediaPlayer` instances. It releases only one out of three each run. `audioTwo()` and `audioThree` assign new `MediaPlayer` instance to the `mp` variable but they don't release the instance which is already stored in there. Do something like:

```
protected void audioTwo() {
    // RELEASING PREVIOUS MEDIAPLAYER
    mp.release();

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;
    switch (randomInt){
    case 1: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.start); mp.start();
    break;
    ...
```

The same goes for `audioThree()`.