# Android wear application only plays media 10 times

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer, wear-os

I am making an android wear application that plays an audio file and flips between two screens. when I click on the screen  a sound is played and the next screen appears. I can do this about ten times before the sound stops but I can continue pressing on the button and go to the next screen. I have already looked at 
[mediaplayer-stops-playing-after-playing-a-few-times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956002/mediaplayer-stops-playing-after-playing-a-few-times). Yet,I do not know how to apply that to my problem and adding mp.release to one of my activities has resulted in a new error. Does anyone know the solution? My sound file is about .1 megabytes and lasts 1 second.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    //used to be final





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //start out with head up
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //handles audio

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                    }
                    //mp.release();


                try {
                    mp.reset();
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                    afd = getAssets().openFd("Coin_Flip_Sound.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("This is Hans and their is a Illegal State ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("This is a IO Exception");
                }



















                //generate random int
                double flip = Math.random();
                if (flip > .5) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Back.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the logcat when I get the error:

```
02-01 14:24:09.675    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-01 14:24:09.699    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-01 14:24:48.601    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:52.410    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:53.249    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:53.418    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:53.631    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:54.293    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 240 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-01 14:24:54.465    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:55.135    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-01 14:24:55.400    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:56.023    2061-2074/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -19)
02-01 14:24:56.059    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ invoke failed: wrong state 0
02-01 14:24:56.059    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-19)
02-01 14:24:56.089    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1010)
02-01 14:24:56.213    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip D/MediaPlayer﹕ setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-01 14:24:56.473    2061-2073/com.example.hansg17.watchflip W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.220ms
02-01 14:24:56.782    2061-2459/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -19)
02-01 14:24:56.787    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ invoke failed: wrong state 0
02-01 14:24:56.787    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-19)
02-01 14:24:56.788    2061-2061/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1010)
```

Logcat after turn off:

```
02-01 14:18:56.884     961-2788/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
02-01 14:18:56.884     961-2788/? E/AudioTrack﹕ AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
02-01 14:18:56.886     961-2788/? E/AudioSink﹕ Unable to create audio track
02-01 14:18:56.887     961-2788/? W/NuPlayerRenderer﹕ openAudioSink: non offloaded open failed status: -19
02-01 14:18:56.887     961-2786/? E/NuPlayer﹕ received error(0xffffffed) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
02-01 14:18:56.887     961-2786/? D/NuPlayerDriver﹕ notifyListener_l(0xb619abc0), (100, 1, -19)
02-01 14:18:56.887    2004-2015/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -19)
02-01 14:18:56.887     961-2788/? W/NuPlayerRenderer﹕ onDrainAudioQueue(): audio sink is not ready
02-01 14:18:56.888     961-2788/? W/NuPlayerRenderer﹕ onDrainAudioQueue(): audio sink is not ready
02-01 14:18:56.891     961-2789/? W/AMessage﹕ failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
02-01 14:18:56.898    2004-2004/com.example.hansg17.watchflip E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-19)
02-01 14:18:56.927    1300-1319/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.hansg17.watchflip/.Back: +56ms
02-01 14:18:57.389    1300-1319/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-01 14:18:57.460    1300-1319/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-01 14:18:57.526    1300-1319/system_process I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

If you want more logcat ask me. There is a lot.

Comment: Just a suggestion, MediaPlayer isn't ideal for short clips like a coin flip. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883883 for sample code using SoundPoolPlayer, might be a better alternative.

Comment: I don't really understand sound pool and there is not much information outside of StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still recommend SoundPool (there's enough info in that SO post I linked to to get you going). But if you'd rather stick with MediaPlayer, I'd suggest moving much of your code out of the `onClick` handler. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    mp.reset();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("Coin_Flip_Sound.mp3");
    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
            afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    mp.prepareAsync();

    ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            }

            try {
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ...
            }

            //generate random int
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

In other words, there's no need to load the asset and `prepare` the `MediaPlayer` every time you tap the button; do that once, in advance.

Also, note that I've used `prepareAsync()` rather than just `prepare()`, moving the filesystem access and `MediaPlayer` initialization off the UI thread.